# PulseAudio loopback module with crackling sound / noise under Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I tried to get audio from my second monitor into Kubuntu through the line-in stereo jack which is now basically working after fiddling with `alsamixer` (un-mute Line & getting volume settings right) and adding `load-module module-loopback` to my `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

My current and biggest problem with this setup is the crackling sound / noise I get while playing audio - even after adjusting the line-in volume to ~5% (everything above that is just painful) and increasing volume on my external amplifier. (Under Windows 10 I have no crackling / sound problems with this setup even with line-in volume of 100%)

**What I've tried so far:**

**1)** Having `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0` (adding the `tsched=0`)
in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` for deactivating timer-based scheduling in PulseAudio which helped other people with crackling sound.

**2)** Combining **1)** with modifications in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` for setting the default fragment number and buffer size in PulseAudio (like here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Static_noise_when_using_headphones)

**3)** Explicitly writing the loopback source & sink with its rate and channels:

```
load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.pci-0000_12_00.3.analog-stereo sink=alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo rate=44100 channels=2
```

And **4)** modifying `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` with `options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1` or `options snd-hda-intel position_fix=2` which was suggested here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PositionReporting

**My system:**

- Kubuntu 17.10, 64 Bit
- Kernel-Version 4.13.0-36-generic
- AMD Ryzen 7 1700X CPU
- 16 GB RAM
- ASRock X370 Taichi motherboard
- Nvidia GTX 1070 GPU

---

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i audio -A2
0e:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10b0:1b81]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
12:00.3 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1457]
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1220]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

---

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfd080000 irq 329                                                                                                                                  
 1 [Audio          ]: USB-Audio - DigiHug USB Audio                                                                                                                                     
                      FiiO DigiHug USB Audio at usb-0000:11:00.3-2, full speed
 2 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfd900000 irq 331
```

---

```
pactl list sources
Quelle #0
        Status: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo.monitor
        Beschreibung: Monitor of DigiHug USB Audio Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
        Abtastwert-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzer-Modul: 7
        Stumm: ja
        Lautstärke: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
                Verteilung 0,00
        Basis-Lautstärke: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        Ziel-Monitor: alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo
        Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 40000 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                device.description = "Monitor of DigiHug USB Audio Analog Stereo"
                device.class = "monitor"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "DigiHug USB Audio"
                alsa.long_card_name = "FiiO DigiHug USB Audio at usb-0000:11:00.3-2, full speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:11:00.3-usb-0:2:1.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "1852"
                device.vendor.name = "GYROCOM C&C Co., LTD"
                device.product.id = "7022"
                device.product.name = "DigiHug USB Audio"
                device.serial = "FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio"
                device.string = "1"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
        Formate:
                pcm

Quelle #1
        Status: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_12_00.3.analog-stereo
        Beschreibung: HD-Audio Generic Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
        Abtastwert-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzer-Modul: 8
        Stumm: nein
        Lautstärke: front-left: 6554 /  10% / -60,00 dB,   front-right: 6554 /  10% / -60,00 dB
                Verteilung 0,00
        Basis-Lautstärke: 6554 /  10% / -60,00 dB
        Ziel-Monitor: k. A.
        Latenz: 30 usec, eingestellt 40000 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC1220 Analog"
                alsa.id = "ALC1220 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfd900000 irq 331"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:12:00.3"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:12:00.3/sound/card2"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "1457"
                device.string = "front:2"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "HD-Audio Generic Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC1220"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec1220,18491220,00100003"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Ports:
                analog-input-front-mic: Vorderes Mikrofon (priority: 8500, not available)
                analog-input-rear-mic: Rückwärtiges Mikrofon (priority: 8200, not available)
                analog-input-linein: Eingang (priority: 8100, available)
        Aktiver Port: analog-input-linein
        Formate:
                pcm
```

---

```
pactl list sinks
Ziel #0
        Status: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo
        Beschreibung: DigiHug USB Audio Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
        Abtastwert-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzer-Modul: 7
        Stumm: nein
        Lautstärke: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
                Verteilung 0,00
        Basis-Lautstärke: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        Quellen-Monitor: alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo.monitor
        Latenz: 46296 usec, eingestellt 40000 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "USB Audio"
                alsa.id = "USB Audio"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "DigiHug USB Audio"
                alsa.long_card_name = "FiiO DigiHug USB Audio at usb-0000:11:00.3-2, full speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:11:00.3-usb-0:2:1.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:11:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "1852"
                device.vendor.name = "GYROCOM C&C Co., LTD"
                device.product.id = "7022"
                device.product.name = "DigiHug USB Audio"
                device.serial = "FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio"
                device.string = "front:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "DigiHug USB Audio Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
                alsa.components = "USB1852:7022"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
        Ports:
                analog-output: Analoge Ausgabe (priority: 9900)
        Aktiver Port: analog-output
        Formate:
                pcm
```

**My basic audio setup:**

Inputs:

- audio coming from second monitor into computer line-in
- all other audio is coming from the system / applications / music

Output:

- USB-DAC/AMP which my headphone is connected to

Comment: What kernel are you running? I had a similar problem a while ago with a Z97 motherboard, and updating the kernel fixed it for me (at the time the Z97 was a new board/chipset). Perhaps try upgrading to the 4.15 kernel?

Comment: At the moment I'm using 4.13.0-36 (generic, newest from the standard repo).
I'm not that versed in Linux, but from what I gathered upgrading to a mainline kernel is kind of risky or rather 'advanced stuff' and can probably excavate/generate new problems? My motherboard is not that new (first Ryzen-generation) so I'd hope any normal fixes should already be included in the current kernel.
But nevertheless I thank you for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Run in terminal `alsamixer`, hit `f5` to select all controls and mute `Mic Boost  (+20db)` if enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I already did that first whilst trying to get the line-in to work. Currently I have all boosts (2x `Mic Boosts` and 1x `Line Boost`) at '0' (no mute-option there) and a setting named `Capture` at 5 (the aforementioned 5% volume). In fact I tried muting all options not related to line-in but no constellation got rid of the problem.

Comment: I don't know if you are still around, but did you ever fix this issue? I am running into the same problem right now. All line-in type ports are creating a buzzing noise and I have to put the volume percentage to %6. I've got a very similar module-loopback configuration above. I've been struggling with this for weeks. All other audio devices play the sound normally but this loopback is what is driving me nuts.

Comment: @meanbunny Hey! Yes, I'm around! But sadly I never fixed the issue... it was one of the reasons I'm now back to Win10 as my main system... >_< (don't like it, but more things work - not driving me nuts all the time)

Comment: @Vorkosik that is unfortunate. I've been looking everywhere for a fix for this. Windows machine has no issue piping the output correctly with great quality to any other audio device but when it goes through this loopback module I can hear the feedback. Makes no sense. I've found at 6% I can't hear it even when high frames are utilized which is nice. Now just trying to get the Microphone fixed.

Comment: @Vorkosik check answer below, this was a ground loop issue for me and is solved with these 2 devices. Not software related at all, I can finally get peace!

Comment: 5 years later I am still encountering this...on Endeavor but I am using pulse and alsa. My mic is a Yeti and that works fine while plugged in to the mic but there are some perks on my soundblaster but I would almost have to run an earbud to hear myself when recording videos and in meetings just to be aware of my levels and whether the neighbor's goats are being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Key items that got this to be fixed for me where the following.

Case Modifications

1. Removed GPU Fan housing, on my GPU there was a protective plastic housing that upon listening physically inside the case was making some noise.
2. Relocated RAM, my RAM was located right up next to an NVMe card so I moved it to the next slots over.
3. Remove shield near GPU for NVMe, on the motherboard there was a protective shield over top of the NVMe stick

Power Modifications

1. Moved power source of both machines to a different outlet. This actually helped reduce a lot of feedback noise as I learned about grounding.

PulseAudio Modification

```
load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-Corsair_CORSAIR_VOID_ELITE_Wireless_Gaming_Dongle-00.multichannel-input sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.3.analog-stereo
load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.pci-0000_09_00.3.analog-stereo sink=alsa_output.usb-Corsair_CORSAIR_VOID_ELITE_Wireless_Gaming_Dongle-00.iec958-stereo


set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Corsair_CORSAIR_VOID_ELITE_Wireless_Gaming_Dongle-00.iec958-stereo
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-Corsair_CORSAIR_VOID_ELITE_Wireless_Gaming_Dongle-00.multichannel-input
set-source-volume alsa_input.pci-0000_09_00.3.analog-stereo 5000

set-card-profile alsa_card.usb-HD_Webcam_USB_HD_Webcam_USB_HD_Webcam_USB-02 off
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_07_00.1 off
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_09_00.3 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo

set-sink-port alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.3.analog-stereo analog-output-lineout
set-source-port alsa_input.pci-0000_09_00.3.analog-stereo analog-input-linein
```

With all of that being said, I do STILL have some feedback noise but only during high GPU framerates. I do believe this to be a power issue and have another part ordered to help reduce this feedback. Basically a ground loop aux device.

Here is also a reference to my struggle with this issue.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1917945#p1917945

**Edit 1**
TURNS OUT, this is actually not software related at all and was a hardware issue. I bought 2 of these and plugged them in between both machines and it has completely fixed the issue. There is no more feedback even at high volumes.
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B019393MV2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019393MV2)

Comment: Gotcha let me update here then.